# Dynamics CRM 2015 Unable to save an Advanced Find query with related entity fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Im using dynamics CRM 2015 On premise.

Im not able to Save/Save as an Advanced Find query view with related entity fields, I have a message error without log.
Im the system admistrator (All permissions are checked)

However, it works when I save the query as a personnal view without adding a related entity field.

There is a screenshot of the occured error:

[image: Occured Error]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the CRM trace logs it's hard to tell what the problem is. Did you publish all customizations? Is your database in shape (transaction log not full etc.)?

Comment: Hi Henk, thank you for your reply. I publish all customizations and the transaction log is not full (Other transactions from other entities are logged)

Comment: Check the event viewer logs on the CRM server, after reproducing the error. I've had similar problems when creating customer roll-up queries on goals through code, and then trying to edit the manually, it can happen, that some of the aliases in your fetch xml are not unique when generated through from CRM. Though event log on the machine should give you some clue.

Comment: I haven't access to the server, I can't check the event viewer logs. The weirdness is that i have the same imported solution on my own CRM server and it works fine!